# Type Resolution in Haskell: MegaParsec/ Parsing a single space

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

If I look at the [documentation for `space`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.17/megaparsec-5.3.1/Text-Megaparsec-Lexer.html) it suggests using `void spaceChar`.

However, if I actually try:

```
x :: Parser ()
x = void spaceChar
```

I get

```
* Couldn't match type `Token s0' with `Char'
    arising from a use of `spaceChar'
  The type variable `s0' is ambiguous
* In the first argument of `void', namely `spaceChar'
  In the expression: void spaceChar
  In an equation for `x': x = void spaceChar
```

I think the expression is correct, but there's something I need to do to convince the type checker. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Show how you define `Parser`. Also, which version of Megaparsec are you using?

Comment: @Mark Isn't that the `Parser` from `Text.Megaparsec.String`? That being said, I cannot reproduce that issue with the `Parser` from `Text.Megaparsec.String`…

Comment: @Zeta, Yes, I suspect this is Megaparsec 5 (according to the link), and I'm having a hard time imagining how this issue could happen... We need a full reproducing example with clarification about actual version of the library used.

Comment: megaparsec 5.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tracked down the issue whilst trying to create a reproduction. The problem was a bit abstruse: I wasn't importing Control.Monad. Instead, it looks like void was being picked up somewhere else (not sure where) and this definition of void caused that error to occur. Thank you for everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

ghci suggests the type `(Token s ~ Char, MonadParsec e s f) => f ()`. That one should work. Where did you get the name `Parser`?

Comment: That gives me

```
    * Could not deduce: Token s0 ~ Char
        arising from a use of spaceChar
      from the context: (Token s ~ Char, MonadParsec e s f)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   x :: (Token s ~ Char, MonadParsec e s f) => f ()
        at BLAH
      The type variable s0 is ambiguous
    * In the first argument of void, namely spaceChar
      In the expression: void spaceChar
      In an equation for `x': x = void spaceChar
```